# Switching between http and https for images located on a sub-domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ssl

My ASP.NET MVC3 site, www.mysite.com, pulls images from images.mysite.com.  When I'm not logged into my site and using SSL, it works flawlessly.  However, when logged in, it get the

> Only secure content is displayed.

message in IE9.  I understand that.  What's the best way to deal with switching URL's for my images?  Should I check to see if I'm currently using SSL and point my images to https://images.mysite.com, otherwise http://images.mysite.com?

EDIT: This is an e-commerce site, so most of the time the site is browsed unsecured. But after login, I still need to pull some of those same images, and of course if they browse back to a regular catalog page, it would need to access images.  Perhaps I will just have to always use https://images.mysite.com.  Just seemed like overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem only happens when you're in a secure page accessing content over http.  So, for pages that can be seen both in http or https, might be as easy as always using https to get the images, regardless if you're in http or https.

Answer (score 1):

You will always get that message if you are pulling content from a non-SSL site when viewing over SSL.  If you site is mostly SSL protected, just always pull images from https://images.mysite.com as you do not get the error if you pull SSL content into a non-SSL site.

Otherwise, you will need to know which pages are only viewable over SSL and which ones are not, and link appropriately.

Lastly, if you site is available over both, you will probably need to look at the [HTTPS server variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to determine if you are on SSL or not and use this to determine your link (http or https).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try prefixing with ~instead of ../ or /? 
This worked for me.

Comment: Actually while very brief it ***does*** provide an answer to the question. To explain further, I think they are saying use `~/Content/images/example.png` instead of `http://images.mysite.com/Content/images/example.png`. Whether that is directly relevant or not is impossible to tell without the question's author showing how they are linking to images, but as it stands it is a valid answer.

Comment: in my case, I was connecting to another site that did pre-processing of the images.  My solution back then in 2012 was to use HTTPS for every page.